# Deleting dynamic array in C++ causes an error

Tags: c++

I have a class called `Myclass`. In the main function, I have created an array object for this class. Whenever I try to delete this dynamically allocated array, the visual studio will say, `Error: Debug Assertion Failed!. Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`. Can you please tell me what is causing this or show me an example of fixing this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Myclass
{
public:    
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Myclass" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Myclass *obj[3] = { new Myclass, new Myclass, new Myclass };

    // Call each object's print function.
    for (int index=0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        obj[index]->print();
    }

    delete[] obj; //Error 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't `new[3]` you did 3 different `new`. So you need to do 3 `delete`, not `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
Myclass *obj[3] = { new Myclass, new Myclass, new Myclass };
```

is not a dynamically allocated array. It is an array with automatic storage, holding pointers to dynamically allocated objects. To properly clean up, you need:

```
delete obj[0];
delete obj[1];
delete obj[2];
```

Because every `new` must be matched with a `delete`, and you can only delete via `delete[]` something that was allocated via `new[]`.

There is no need for any dynamic allocation here, just do:

```
Myclass obj[3] = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `delete[]` operator should only be used for arrays created using the `new[]` operator, which your `obj` isn't. You have a *fixed* array of pointers to objects, each of which must be deleted as such:

```cpp
    for (int index=0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        delete obj[index];
    }
```

Alternatively, you can create your object array using the `new[]` operator, then delete the array with `delete[]`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Myclass* obj = new Myclass[3];
    // Call each object's print function.
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        obj[index].print(); // Note: Use "." here, not "->"
    }
    delete[] obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, as 463035818_is_not_a_number has said in their answer, there is a *far* simpler method here.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for deleting the "error" that was an error!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `obj` is declared as an array with automatic storage duration with the element type `Myclass *`.

```
Myclass *obj[3] = { new Myclass, new Myclass, new Myclass };
```

That is it is an array of pointers not a pointer.

Each element of the array is indeed a pointer that points to a  dynamically allocated memory. So as the array contains three elements you need to call the operator `delete` three times for each element.

It is simpler to do that in the range-based for loop.

For example

```
for ( auto &item : obj ) 
{
    delete item;
    item = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you allocated the array wrong.
You should write `Myclass* obj = new Myclass[3];`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfect.
I would only add this is not a good style code, if you "think in C++". This is a rather C style code.
First of all, when you are coding in C++ and is not obligued to use C-compatible code, be cautious whenever you see yourself using a C pointer.
In this case, if instead of using a C array of C pointers, you had used a std::vector of MyClass objects, the vector destructor would have called your class destructor for each element, which I think is what you wanted.
My suggestion: change the C array to std::vector and you will be happier. Look how you could have implemented it, using C++11 features and forgetting old C stuff:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <vector>

class Myclass
{
public:    
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Myclass" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World" << endl;

    vector<Myclass> obj(3);
    
    // Call each object's print function.
    for (auto instance : obj)
    {
        instance.print();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you don't even need to worry about deleting the objects, since the vector destructor will be called when the function goes out of scope, and it will take care of calling Myobjects' destructors. Much cleaner and safer code.

Or, in case performance is a very bottleneck for you and you need a static array, if you are using C++11 or later, you also can use std::array, a less "wild" option (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

So that is the tip I leave for you, if coding in C++, use the best this language can offer, and try to forget dangerous and wild old C features. C is good as a lightweight and simpler language, when you need it. But everyone knows it is dangerous (and you have just stumbled on it).
This book of the Bjarne focuses on teaching C++ from scratch, leaving behind the not always productive C legacy:
[Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://www.amazon.com.br/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-English-ebook/dp/B00KPTEH8C/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=bjarne&qid=1634667129&sr=8-2&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.25548f35-0de7-44b3-b28e-0f56f3f96147)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yes, I tried. But stackoverflow said I still dont have enough reputation to add commants :/

Comment: well, at least it allows leaving a comment in my own response. Anyway, it would be a rather big comment ;)